# pytest leaks attrs objects between tests

Tags: python, pytest, python-attrs

I am trying to run two tests in pytest with two different instances of an attr class (returned from a function-scoped fixture), as input arguments. The first msg object also shows up in the second test. My example:

```
import attr
import pytest
import uuid

@attr.s
class Receiver:
    internal_dict = attr.ib(default=dict())

    def send_message(self, msg):
        self.internal_dict[msg] = msg

@pytest.fixture
def msg():
    yield uuid.uuid1()

@pytest.fixture
def receiver():
    yield Receiver()

def test_send_msg_1(msg, receiver):
    receiver.send_message(msg)
    assert len(receiver.internal_dict) == 1

def test_send_msg_2(msg, receiver):
    receiver.send_message(msg)
    print("internal_dict:{}".format(receiver.internal_dict))
    assert len(receiver.internal_dict) == 1  # FAILS
```

How is mutable state leaking between the two tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code shares the *same* `dict()` instance as mutable default:

```
@attr.s
class Receiver:
    internal_dict = attr.ib(default=dict())
```

Consider instead using a factory:

```
@attr.s
class Receiver:
    internal_dict = attr.ib(factory=dict)
```

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with pytest, and everything to do with the way you defined the `Receiver` class.  Even though your pytest fixtures were producing two different instances `Receiver()`, they both shared the same `internal_dict` attribute, because the value `default=dict()` is evaluated *once* at class definition time.

Comment: so this error could be reproduced without attrs with a dict,  in an __init__ defined poorly..?

Comment: Yes, an equivalent 'bug' could be created, without using attr.s, if you defined an init function something like `def __init__(self, internal_dict={}): self.internal_dict = internal_dict`.